# Autofill inputs when select change

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a mysql table, named clients, that i use on of the rows to fill the options of a select.

What i'm trying to do, is to autofill 2 inputs with the client information when one of the options is selected.

To achieve this, i'm using JavaScript linked to a php page that makes a request to the DB and fills in the input forms, but i must have some error that i can't figure out.

I'm a bit new to PHP, so it turns out difficult to me, to understand whats wrong with my code.

This is the form

```
    <form action="insert/insertReport.php" id="newReport" method="get">
       <div id="txtHint" class="form-group"> </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="namefat">Cliente</label>
         <br>
         <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" class="form-control" name="client" id="client" onchange="showUser(this.value)">

         <?php
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            { echo ' 
               <option>'.$row['namefat'].'</option>';

            }?>

          </select>
       </div>
</form>
```

This form is currently on a page called newreports.php and this is the query i use to fill out the options.

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'user';
$db_pass = 'pass';
$db_name = 'name';

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());   
}

$sql = 'SELECT * 
        FROM clients';

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
```

So, like i said before, i'm using a JavaScript to make request to db on change. This is the JS.

```
function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getclient.php?namefat="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
```

And this is the php page, that handles the request.

```
    <?php
    $q = intval($_GET['namefat']);

    $db_host = 'localhost';
        $db_user = 'user';
        $db_pass = 'pass';
        $db_name = 'name';

        $con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
        if (!$conn) {
            die ('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());   
        }

    mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM clients WHERE namefat = '".$q."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<input type="text" name="region" class="form-control" id="region" value=".$row['region']">";
    echo "<input type="text" name="client_type" class="form-control" id="client_type" value=".$row['client_type']">";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

For some reason, the inputs are not autofilled.
I leave a print of the db table structure.

[DB TABLE STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxk8h.png)

Can anyone understand what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not setting value for "option" tag

Comment: @SajjadAli but the value should be empty? cause i'm trying adding the value of the id and the inputs still don't get populated with the option selected.

Comment: can you check what are you getting in variable $q by using echo $q?
also your table does not have "namefat" colums that you are using in your where condition

Comment: @SajjadAli Sorry, i took a print screen of the wrong table. I'm getting server error... So, something must be wrong with the code.

Comment: are you entering in your "While" loop ?

Comment: If yes, then try replace following lines


    echo '<input type="text" name="region" class="form-control" id="region" value="'.$row['region'].'">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="client_type" class="form-control" id="client_type" value="'.$row['client_type'].'">';

Comment: @SajjadAli YES, that worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please to help you. I am posting answer which could be helpful others and if you accept and up vote my answer that would appreciate my effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem is that you are not properly concatenating your $row['region'] as value for your input boxes.

Try replacing these lines of code in your while loop

```
echo "<input type="text" name="region" class="form-control" id="region" value=".$row['region']">";
echo "<input type="text" name="client_type" class="form-control" id="client_type" value=".$row['client_type']">";
```

By

```
echo '<input type="text" name="region" class="form-control" id="region" value="'.$row['region'].'">';
echo '<input type="text" name="client_type" class="form-control" id="client_type" value="'.$row['client_type'].'">';
```

Also, your code is open for [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). instead of directly passing values to your query, [Prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) are the recommended way of dealing with when there is a user input values passing in you query.